# How to change Map Scale programmaticaly in C# WinForm Project

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I have created form with **axMapControl** and **comboBox** with values of possible scales (e.g. 1:1 000 000, 1: 500 000, etc).

How can I change current map scale programmaticaly by using value from selectedItem taken from Combobox?

Answer (score 3):

You can set [`IMap.MapScale`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/MapScale_Property/001200000m9v000000/) to set the current map scale.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
IMap _map = ArcMap.Document.FocusMap;
_map.MapScale = Your_Value;
```

For more information see this : [IMap interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000803000000) and [IMap.MapScale Property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000m9v000000)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem in obtaining map scales and I solved it in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/88717/24470) to [How to get a list of map scales programmatically in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88573/how-to-get-a-list-of-map-scales-programmatically-in-arcmap).