# How to get a list of map scales programmatically in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, cartography, scale-bar

I need to get all map scales, which are shown in the ArcMap scalebar.
I need list of value, something like:

```
1:1500
1:3000
1:6000
1:12000
1:24000
1:50000
1:100000
```

Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: You have arcobjects as a tag but no mention of it in your Question body.  I recommend editing your Question to make it more obvious if you are looking for an ArcObjects solution.

Comment: Also, I am curious as to why you would want to read this list when you can set your scale to any value you like, and an ArcGIS for Desktop user can add/remove values from that list i.e. it should not be considered static.  PS ArcPy can also be the source of a programmatic solution, but not in this case.

Comment: I develop tools for ArcGIS and I wanna have combobox with same data. I think it is convenient for users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, maybe my question was not clear enough, but I found the solution, and it simple enough.

[IDisplayTransformationScales](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000000s4000000) interface provides access to this data.

using .NET it look like:

```
var mxDocument = (IMxDocument)_application.Document;
var activeView = (IActiveView)mxDocument.FocusMap;
var dts = (IDisplayTransformationScales)activeView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;
var scales = Enumerable.Range(0, dts.UserScaleCount)
                       .Select(x => dts.GetUserScale(x))
                       .ToArray();
```

if you want use scale format defined in ArcMap you should use [ScaleFormat](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ScaleFormatClass_Class/0042000002q2000000/) class.

I would be very appreciated if someone tell me a way to get all scale formats.

Comment: Wow, good job finding that. There were no references to it on either of ESRI's forums or anywhere else really. Unless you know the magic word `IDisplayTransformationScales` that is :)